# Как реализовать в Джанго проверку на дубликаты

Tags: python, django

Нужно сделать проверку на дубликаты, при вводе в форму данных, и все это, чтобы работало без перезагрузки страницы, использовался метод ajax, плюс если дубликат есть - нам показало б модальное окно с уведомлением.
`unique_together` отлично проверяет на дубликаты, вопрос, как `unique_together` подружить с ajax и чтобы в результате еще модальное окно, если дубликат есть, показалось?
Спасибо.

Comment: Написать представление, принимающее ajax-запросы и отдающее json-ответы, и написать javascript-функцию, делающую запросы к этому представлению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схема примерно следующая:

1. JS перехватывает submit формы и получает введенные данные
2. Полученные данные отправляются post ajax'ом во вью
3. Вью проводит валидацию принимаемых параметров и рендерит html шаблон с результатами формы
4. В шаблоне можно применить проверку на наличие ошибок у какого-либо поля, выглядит это примерно так, почитать про ошибки в формах можно [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually):

   ```
   {% if form.fieldname.errors %}
       create modal window
   {% endif %}
   ```
5. Заменяем старую форму на новую в success ajax запроса.

   - форму можно поместить в div блок и дать ему id, что бы данные старой формы можно было заменить новой (валидированной).